# I want to calculate the sum of ages of the enteries, I am not sure of how to do it?

Tags: java

This is a program that takes in entries of a group of people asks them for data such as age and name... it then should calculate the mean of the ages of the entries.

```java
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Assignment2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int person;
    String nameOfPerson;
    double ageOfPerson;
    double standardDeviation;
    double total = 0;
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("How many entries?");
    
    person = scan.nextInt();
    
    String[] names = new String[person];
    
    for(int counter =0; counter < person; counter++) {
       System.out.println("Enter the name of person"+(counter+1));
    
       names[counter]= scan.next();
       if (person==1);
          System.out.println("Please enter the age of person"+(counter+1));
       ageOfPerson = scan.nextDouble();    
    }    
  }    
}
```

Comment: You should try to solve it yourself first.

Comment: This looks like a homework or some course question. I don't think stackoverflow is here to do your work. If you can do the math you will find a solution yourself.

Comment: But anyway here are some hints. You can ask for: how to store a list of persons with properties (age, name), how to iterate over a list of elements of some type, ask something about the curios if-condition, ask something about the output/input behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (person==1);
          System.out.println("Please enter the age of person"+(counter+1));
```

First of all - here you have empty "if" expression, fix it.

If you need to calculate the sum, you just need to use

```
ageOfPerson += scan.nextDouble();
```

Each iteration this double will be increased